# Error in Unbeatable Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

While going through the code for Unbeatable Tic Tac Toe Bot I found this code inside a function.

```
def __init__(self,other=None):
    self.player = 'X'
    self.opponent = 'O'
    self.empty = '.'
    self.size = 3
    self.fields = {} # A dictionary
    for y in range(self.size):
        for x in range(self.size):
            self.fields[x,y] = self.empty
```

The `fields` attribute represents a dictionary.
What does `self.fields[x,y]` represent?
Does `x` represent a column and `y` represent a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, `x,y` is a tuple, so it's the same as:

```
self.fields[(x,y)] = self.empty
```

It's equivalent to:

```
k = (x, y)
self.fields[k] = self.empty
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! Does x represent column and y represent row in pyhton code here? In programming languages like cpp, we say x represent row and y represent column in a[x][y]

Comment: In this context, there is no concept of row vs. column from Python's perspective.  `fields` is a dictionary, and the keys can be any immutable types, including strings, tuples, etc.

Comment: Ok got u. Thanks for the help! :)